# Swift: Generic Protocol Cannot invoke with an argument list of type

Tags: swift, xcode, generics, swift4

Trying to create a generic protocol with associatedtype.

I get an error when I try to access a method from the delegate:

```
Cannot invoke 'numberOfSections' with an argument list of type '(containerView: UITableView)'
```

Code:

```
protocol ViewDelegate: class {

    associatedtype ContainerView  
    associatedtype Model 

    func numberOfSections(containerView: ContainerView)
    func aMethodThatTakesNoArugments()
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var newView = AnyView<ViewController>()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        newView.delegate = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: ViewDelegate {
    typealias ContainerView = UITableView  
    typealias Model = Int

    func numberOfSections(containerView: ContainerView) {
        // do something with containerView
    }

    func aMethodThatTakesNoArugments() {}
}

class AnyView<Delegate: ViewDelegate>: UIView {

    weak var delegate: Delegate?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func getData() {
        delegate?.aMethodThatTakesNoArugments()  // This compiles fine
        delegate?.numberOfSections(containerView: UITableView()) // Get a compiler error on this line (I am passing an argument):
        // Cannot invoke 'numberOfSections' with an argument list of type '(containerView: UITableView)'
    }
}
```

I have a feeling I am missing something.  Method that takes no arguments compiles fine; however if I call a method that does take an arugment, I get a compile error.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying. Your `ViewDelegate` does not have `numberOfSections` defined. Why do you think you can call it?

Comment: I am sorry.  I was trying to further simplify and made an error.  Fixed.

Comment: I see. I have no time to write an answer, but when you declare class as `AnyView<Delegate: ViewDelegate>`, `Delegate` may be any type which conforms to `ViewDelegate`. It's associated type may not be `UITableView`. Add a constraint for generic parameter `Delegate`.

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry, can you please elaborate.  Do you mean use a `where` clause?  But where would I add it?

Comment: I got it to compile with the following constraint: `class AnyView<Delegate: ViewDelegate>: UIView where Delegate.ListView == UITableView`.  However, I need to be able to use AnyView with TableView or a CollectionView

Comment: Just a quick Design point, it looks like you're trying cram in some kind of `UITableView` functionality into a normal `UIView` with Type Erasure. If that's your goal, I would highly recommend going the other direction and making a specialized _subclass_ of UIView, rather than trying to make a more generic View and Delegate connection, for what appears to be a special situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is due to the compiler not being able to tell what Type `ContainerView` is supposed to be.

You're only defining it for `ViewController`, but the Delegate could be literally any class or struct, not just ViewController.

There are a number of ways to fix this, but it's unclear what exactly you're trying to accomplish here, so I'll just give a couple examples:

as @OOPer mentioned, you could constraint your `Delegate` generic to force conformance to UITableView:

```
class AnyView<Delegate: ViewDelegate>: UIView where Delegate.ContainerView == UITableView
```

A similar option would be to simply define the protocol with the desired type:

```
protocol ViewDelegate: class {
    func numberOfSections(containerView: ContainerView)
    func aMethodThatTakesNoArugments()
}
```

If you need more flexibility, another option would be to add another generic Type:

```
class AnyView<Delegate: ViewDelegate, ContainerViewType>: UIView where Delegate.ContainerView == ContainerViewType
```

Comment: Thank you!  I also don't like the idea of passing `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` known to `UIView`; however, it's not my design decision, but have to roll with it.  What would you recommend I use If I would like flexibility of being able to pass either `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` into `ViewDelegate`

Comment: If you want to use an `associatedtype`, you have to know what the Type is. Your options are to get rid of the associatedtype, pass the specific Type to where you're using it, not use them, or constrain the associatedtype to a Type all your consumers have in common. (could use another protocol)

Comment: Thanks.  Can I constraint it to multiple Types?  `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`

Comment: No, but you could make a `Protocol` that both adhere to and constrain it to that.